# Spring Restart Application Context after RegisterShutDownHook

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, applicationcontext

I'm trying to learn Spring so i'm rookie on this subject.And i am bit lost in this test class because trying to test multiple subject in just one method.First;I want to shutdown application context and then start again.Is it possible?Other than this; i am trying to modify changeBeanScope behavior.I change my test class that using xml configuration to using java config class.So right now i can't use scope name parameter.Is there any better approach?Here is a test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = LearnSpringConfig.class)
public class BeanScopeTest  {
final String testMessageOne = "Message One";
final String testMessageTwo = "Message Two";
static String beanMessage;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext  applicationContext;

@Autowired
SingletonBean bean;

@Autowired
SingletonBean beanSingleton;


@Test
public void testBean(){

    bean.setMessage(testMessageOne);
    beanMessage = bean.getMessage();
    assertEquals(testMessageOne,beanMessage);



    beanMessage = beanSingleton.getMessage();
    SingletonBean.singletonBeanLogger.info("Bean Two:"+beanMessage);        
    assertEquals(testMessageOne,beanMessage); //Test SingletonBean

    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).registerShutdownHook();//Test Bean Lifecyle

    SingletonBean beanThree = new SingletonBean();
    BeanActs.changeBeanScope("scopeBean", "prototype");
    beanThree.setMessage(testMessageTwo);
    SingletonBean.singletonBeanLogger.info("Bean Three:"+beanThree.getMessage());

    SingletonBean beanFour = new SingletonBean();
    beanMessage = beanFour.getMessage();
    SingletonBean.singletonBeanLogger.info("Bean Four:"+beanMessage);       
    assertEquals(null,beanMessage); 
}
```

I'm trying to change bean class scope with changeBeanScope.

```
    public static void changeBeanScope(String beanID,String scope){
         ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:src/main/resources/Beans.xml");
         BeanDefinitionRegistry registry =  (BeanDefinitionRegistry)context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
         BeanDefinition def = registry.getBeanDefinition(beanID);
         def.setScope(scope);
         registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanID, def);
}
```

And my config class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"learn.spring.LearningSpring"})
public class LearnSpringConfig {

@Bean
public SingletonBean bean(){
    return new SingletonBean();
}   
}
```